# How to add elastic-apm-agent.jar to PCF?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, pcf, elastic-apm

I have downloaded elastic-apm-agent.jar on my local which is monitoring locally deployed spring boot micro service. Now I want to add same jar to PCF.